# Array of Function Pointers as Parameter

Tags: c++

After creating an array of function pointers
     `void(*array[d1])(int);`

How can I pass it as a parameter of a function?

```
callFunctions(int array[],int size){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        *array[i](0);
    }
}
```

Compiler keeps saying my parameter type is wrong

Comment: I would prefer syntax with `std::array<void(*)(int), d1>`.

Comment: interesting, maybe I'm just too novice to see the difference

Comment: IMO, It is clearer, in particular to pass/return argument: `void foo(const std::array<void(*)(int), d1>& a)` against `void foo(void(*(&a)[d1])(int))`. `using`/`typedef` might also be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the functions using the function pointer `array` like following:

```
 (*array[i]) ( 0 );
```

Update you `callFunctions` as:

```
/* void */ callFunctions( void (*fptr[ ])(int), int size )
{
   // (*fptr[ i ])( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but still doesn't like how I am passing the array in the function

Comment: @R.Velazquez Sorry didn't noticed. I updated the post.

Comment: array[i] ( 0 ); is also a legal call but dereference notation helps to figure out how to write the pointer